# Deleting equal number of records with positive and negative values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having multiple negative and positive values, i want to delete only those number of records from table which are having negative values and have the same positive values . I'm not sure how to explain this scenario...

I will give a brief example-

I have a table with 6 records in which 2 records are with negative value and 4 record with  positive

```
  Name | number
    A | 1
    A |-1
    A | 1
    A |-1
    A | 1
    A | 1
```

So here i want to delete equal number of records of negative value and positive value
so my output should be

```
Name | Number
A | 1
A | 1
```

Comment: Without a primary key column or row number, how could we determine which rows to retain, assuming your logic can be implemented?

Comment: Please update your question with the actual table definition, including primary key.

Comment: Try use DISTINCT and just use >0 filter negative

Comment: that is what the main concern is...i have given an example in the real time records would not be coming next to each other i.e. -1 won't be coming after 1...so is there where we can check the total count of these negative value rows and only delete that many positive value records of same value

Comment: Without an ordering, any query won't even be deterministic.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

By using Row_number

```
;WITH CTE AS (

select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 RN from Table1 )

Select Name, number from CTE WHERE RN NOT IN (1,0)
```

Comment: Not sure this will work or not but definitely your row function have helped me to get me my resultset. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @user3895001 if it helps you can rate as answer

Comment: i tried doing that but they won't accept rating from a user with less than 15 points

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @negvalrecs int = (select COUNT(*) from tab where Number < 0)

delete 
from tab
where Number < 0

delete top (@negvalrecs)
from tab
where Number > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query assumes that your table has either a column called `id` which is either a primary key or some other means to order your records.  Without any order, your question cannot be answered, and in fact the data sample you showed us would have no meaning, since internally records have no order in a SQL database.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.number, SUM(t2.number) as sum
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number
)
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS cutoff
    FROM cte1
    WHERE sum = 0
)
SELECT t.*
FROM yourTable t
WHERE t.id > (SELECT cutoff FROM cte2)
```

Note that I used the old school way of computing a running sum because you never told us the version of SQL Server which you are using.  Hence, I didn't want to make assumptions about what you have available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs!

I have a solution for it. We will be needing row number function for it.

```
--Providing row number to rows
select *,row_number () over (partition by name,number order by name) R into #1 from Table

--Taking negative values
select * into #2 from #1 where number<0

--Now Deleting those records from the main table by joining this table
delete #1 from #1 a inner join #2 b on a.name=b.name and a.number=b.number and a.r<=b.r

delete #1 from #1 a inner join #2 b on a.name=b.name and a.number=-(b.number) and a.r<=b.r
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar problem and this is how I resolved it. 
I also had records in table where there we no negatives for a given name the union all is to bring such records.

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.number 
 FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT name, number FROM table where number < 0) t2
ON
 t1.name = t2.name and t1.number = t2.number
WHERE t1.number > 0 and t2.number IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.name, t1.number
 FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT name, number FROM table where number < 0) t2
ON
 t1.name = t2.name 
WHERE t1.number > 0 and t2.number IS  NULL;`
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this,**

```
delete from table_name
where substring(ltrim(rtrim(number)),1,1)='-'
```

Comment: 1 ,-1 are just dummy values they might be anything

Comment: ya i got your question. above query will delete records only which start with '-' sign

Comment: @mangeshdesai, for that you can directly use ... WHERE number < 0

Comment: but if data type varchar then might be 'number < 0' will not work for varchar.

Comment: @user3895001 try using above query which i have posted